# Remove query string and index.php from requested URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, internationalization

I have an internationalized website where the structure is:

```
English:   /(.*)
Spanish:   /es/(.*)
French:    /fr/(.*)
Chinese:   /zh/(.*)
```

So for example, the about us page would be:

```
English:   /aboutus/
Spanish:   /es/aboutus/
French:    /fr/aboutus/
Chinese:   /zh/aboutus/
```

All subdirectories are real subdirectories, and all requests are rewritten back to the `index.php` file in that subdirectory and a GET variable `lang=xx` is appended to be sent to PHP.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^=]*)=(.*)
RewriteRule ^es/(.*/)?$ $1/index.php?lang=es&%1=%2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*/)?$ $1/index.php?lang=es [NC,L]
```

This appeared to work fine, except somehow, somewhere, I had another error and Google indexed my entire site with the actual rewritten URLs, like:

```
https://www.example.com/aboutus/index.php?lang=fr
```

This then messed up another part of my site, as well as creating duplicate content. I can partially fix it by getting rid of the `index.php`, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)?index.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

However if I try to remove the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=es$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/?es(.*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?es(.*)?$
RewriteRule (.*) /es/$1? [R=301,L]
```

I then get an infinite loop between what I want and appending `index.php` to it:

```
$ curl -I -L https://www.example.com/aboutus/index.php?lang=es
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:13:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/aboutus/?lang=es
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:13:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/es/aboutus/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:13:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/es/aboutus/index.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:13:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/es/aboutus/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:13:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/es/aboutus/index.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:13:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/es/aboutus/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I also tried removing the last `?` from the rule, which didn't quite work either, but at least I don't have a loop:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=es$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/?es(.*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?es(.*)?$
RewriteRule (.*) /es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Result:

```
$ curl -I -L https://www.example.com/aboutus/index.php?lang=es
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:18:31 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/aboutus/?lang=es
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:18:31 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/es/aboutus/?lang=es
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 01:18:31 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=pv84bbm3fropancqpcrmkle6h1; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I tried to combine the last one above with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=es
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?es(.*)?$
RewriteRule (.*) /es/$1? [R=301,L]
```

However this rule does not seem to have any effect.

I've gotta be close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking it back to the beginning of your problem, which are Google indexed urls like `https://www.example.com/aboutus/index.php?lang=fr`, you should have those 2 rules to correct it in one step

```
# Redirect /some-path/index.php?lang=fr to /fr/some-path/ (same for es and zh)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.*)/?index\.php\?lang=(fr|es|zh)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L]

# Redirect /some-path/index.php?lang=en to /some-path/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.*)/?index\.php\?lang=en\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Note: don't forget to clear your browser's cache before trying (otherwise your old rules may interfere and intermediate cases won't match those rules above)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try a little later.

Comment: Sorry for my slowness. It worked like a charm! 25 pointies to you!